# Switching back to the standard keyboard for UITextField with custom InputView (monotouch)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm using a custom input view on a UITextField by setting its InputView property; it works great.

However, in certain conditions I need to switch back to the standard keyboard input. Intuitively, I'm trying to set InputView property to null, but this doesn't work - an exception is thrown.

Looking at UITextField.InputView implementation, it starts like this:

```
public void set_InputView(UIView value)
{
  if (!value)
  {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(value);
  }
...
```

So, it is obvious that setting InputView to null is no-go ...

Does anybody know how it can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the bindings, I've fixed it and the next release will accept null.  In the mean time you could set it to null with a workaround:

```
NSObject nil = new NSObject (IntPtr.Zero);
this.InputView = nil;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't compile: Error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject' to `MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView'. If I add an explicit cast this.InputView = (UIView)nil  - it compiles, but fails at runtime with InvalidCastException  :-(

Comment: Looks I got it working by using  this.InputView = new UIView(IntPtr.Zero). Is it the proper workaround? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Its an acceptible workaround until the next version, its a bit of a hack, but just due to poor style.